# Google scholar not updating PDF link to published conference version from older arXiv link

Tags: conference, computer-science, arxiv, google-scholar

One of our paper was arXiv'd before getting accepted at a conference.
The conference has its own publishing site where all the accepted papers are publicly available.

For our paper, Google Scholar has the arXiv PDF link. However, we want the PDF link from the conference website to replace the arXiv PDF link.

I have tried updating the PDF link manually, but I found no options to do that. I also created a new entry with the updated publication details (without the PDF link) hoping it would automatically detect the new link, but it still got the arXiv link instead.

I am now thinking of deleting or taking down the arXiv version entirely so that there remains only one version of the publication. I'm not sure if I should do that. Please suggest what I should do here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Google Scholar usually first indexes papers appearing within 7-14 days of their original announcement in arXiv, and then again within 2-3 days for minor tweaks that might have occurred after announcement. Any subsequent replacements or other metadata changes will appear in Google Scholar during their twice-yearly full system reindex, where they re-harvest all their data sources (details are at [item number 1 in their documentation](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#troubleshooting)). Typically these indices occur in January and July.

You cannot delete or takedown the arXiv paper (the license applied at the time of submission cannot be revoked at-will), but there's a fairly strong evidence that the canonical link to the conference version should appear after January's re-index.

Comment: This is helpful for me for a similar issue with Google Scholar, +1