# How long does it take for the authors list update on arXiv to be recognized by Google Scholar?

Tags: publications, arxiv, google-scholar

We recently updated an arXiv version of an article and added more authors.

https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.03538

But after about two weeks, Google Scholar still shows the old authors.

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=widesim&btnG=

How long does it take for the authors list update on arXiv to be recognized by Google Scholar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google scholar not updating PDF link to published conference version from older arXiv link](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/203886/google-scholar-not-updating-pdf-link-to-published-conference-version-from-older)

Comment: @DavidRaveh Pretty much yes. Thank you. Do you know when exactly is the January reindex?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you must edit the list on your profile.  These changes should then propagate automatically to the others sharing the article.

Technically they are separate documents but I think most people only want the most recent preprint to show up and I am unsure if google scholar ever fixes this automatically.

Comment: Google scholar does eventually fix it, see this answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/203886/google-scholar-not-updating-pdf-link-to-published-conference-version-from-older